# How to upload my own library to jcentre or maven in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, jcenter

I was trying to make one of my module library to bintray and jcentre so that I can compile my other projects just using compile thing.

I never did it before so don't have any specialization about it. I did google it and found some tutorial, this one looked pretty good explanation.

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

But somehow I failed to do it. There are a couple of problems which I'm facing currently and didn't get any reply from them. Please help me..

Problems:
1> I'm using windows system so I'm not able to do the gpg --gen-key thing for ssh public key. I got various theories like there are only one ssh public key and since I have git setup in my system so basically that ssh key should work, but thats not working with this procedure.

2> For windows they say to use cygwin, I'm totally clueless regarding cygwin.

3> I tried to skip that part and went on to copying the classpath then I don't know what bintray.apikey should I be using.

4> After that it says to paste these two lines at the end of the file
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'

I'm again clueless which file? I tried with all the build.gradle files didnt work. I tried with gradle wrapper didn't work.

5> Skipped that too, now went on to gradlew install step, it gave error.

I got another link, another tutorial
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582

This one is a bit different, and I'm still facing some problem in this too.

I don't have any idea where to add the artifacts part. And skipping that step is giving error while installing.

I have totally lost it. Please help..

EDIT: Now I'm getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':libraryutilities:install'.
```

> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
>   Failed to install artifact https://github.com/Aritra1704/UtilsLibrary:libraryutilities:aar:1.0.1: C:\Users\Aritra.m2\repository\https:\github\com\Aritra1704\UtilsLibrary\libraryutilities\1.0.1\libraryutilities-1.0.1.aar (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I opened that folder too, its empty, what might I have done wrong?

EDIT 2:

module build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'UtilitiesLibrary'

```
publishedGroupId = 'com.arpaul.libraryutilities'
libraryName = 'Utilities Library'
artifact = 'UtilitiesLibrary'

libraryDescription = 'Various utilities like Calendar date format, Data type conversion, Bitmap conversions.'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/Aritra1704/UtilsLibrary'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/Aritra1704/UtilsLibrary.git'

libraryVersion = '0.0.1'

developerId = 'aritra1704'
developerName = 'Aritra'
developerEmail = 'aritra1704@gmail.com'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Comment: You could just leave your code in Github and use JitPack.   https://jitpack.io